# How to convert NumberDecimal to float using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose and I am trying to convert NumberDecimal to float.

Can anyone please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: not sure what You mean... `parseFloat()`?

Comment: @FlashThunder Yes, but as it is an Object it won't work I guess ?

Comment: It's represented as NumberDecimal is mongo, but in node it's just a string... that should work.

Comment: @FlashThunder I was checking in the debugger and there it was showing Object, that's why never thought of applying parseFloat directly, thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome :-) I can post it as answer, so other people having similar problem would know. Accepting it would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `parseFloat()` on it. As simple as that.